# how to show dynamic data in js script on ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

i have a static script of chart which is shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
        text: "Converting in Local Time"
      },

      axisX:{
        title: "time",
        gridThickness: 2,
        interval:2, 
        intervalType: "hour",        
        valueFormatString: "HH:mm:ss", 
        labelAngle: -20
      },
      axisY:{
        title: "distance"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [//array
        {x: new Date("2016-03-28 15:28:30"), y: 26 },
        {x: new Date( "2016-03-28 18:28:30" ), y: 38  },
        {x: new Date( "2016-03-28 21:28:30" ), y: 43 }

        ]
      },

        {        
        type: "line",
       dataPoints: [//array
       {x: new Date("2016-03-28 14:28:30"), y: 20 },
       {x: new Date( "2016-03-28 16:28:30" ), y: 38 },
      {x: new Date( "2016-03-28 20:28:30" ), y: 13 }

       ]


     }

      ]
    });

chart.render();
}
</script>
```

the above x and y data is static but i want to shown it dynamically. i have a data in loop how can i place that loop beside the static value of x and y.

i have the dynamic data in this:

```
<% for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++)
  {
  console.log(tags[i]);
 var data= points.points[tags[i]];
for (var n=0; n < data.length; n++)
{
console.log(data[n].dateTime);
console.log(data[n].value);

}
  }
  %>
```

how should i place the above in place of dataPoints loop?